# Custom per-site stylesheet extension for Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, css

I'm looking for an extension what will apply a specific stylesheets to specific websites. For example `googlestyle.css` would go with Google.com and `superuserstyle.css` would go with superuser.com.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [Stylish](http://userstyles.org/help/stylish). ([official addon page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108))

> **Stylish** lets you easily manage user styles. Add, delete, enable, disable, and organize with a few clicks of a mouse, no code to edit, no obscure configuration to find. Stylish's companion website, userstyles.org, hosts tens of thousands of user styles made by other Stylish users that you can try.

(Despite the above, it's just as easy to use your own stylesheets for any website).

Comment: You should almost certainly not use Stylish anymore due to trust / privacy issues: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylish#Privacy_issues