# How can I change a specific website's style?

Tags: browser-addons, html, css

I have a specific website I often use (specifically, http://www.pygame.org/), which has an awful color scheme.  I would like to change the color scheme of the site, but I haven't been able to find a good tool for the job.

Some basic requirements:

- It should not be universal to all websites, or affect other websites.
- I want this to be semi-automatic.  I don't want to have to re-define the theme for each page of the site.
- I want to continue to access the site online (I don't want a local copy of the entire site)
- Not OS-specific (browser-specific is okay)

I am currently using Firefox, but I am also happy with Chrome.

There may be some limitations on what is able to be done automatically, as the CSS seems to be embedded in the HTML (and some also in the HTML tags).  I would like to remove as much of the green as possible.

Is there an existing extension/add-on that does this?

Comment: Possible Dupe: [Custom per-site stylesheet extension for Firefox](http://superuser.com/questions/128666/custom-per-site-stylesheet-extension-for-firefox)

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/?src=external-userstyleshome

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with making a user CSS file, my instructions here may be of use to you: http://superuser.com/questions/234952/understanding-css-for-user-styling-in-a-browser/465964#465964

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all that after learning how to make [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) user scripts, which is not that difficult.

[Here is a collection](http://userscripts.org/) of user scripts made by other people, which will show you what can be done, and what is required.

[Firefox needs an extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for using user scripts, but Chrome has the ability built-in.